# How to get class of item selected in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 images (.field-img) , wrapped in a container (.group-container),

each of the images are in a unique field id, so my tpl is broken down into

```
<div class=group-container>
 <div id=field1>
  <div class=field-img>
 </div></div>
 <div id=field2>
  <div class=field-img>
 </div></div>
</div>
```

my js is

```
$(".group-container .field-img").click(function() {
 alert(".group-container .field-img");
```

what I would like is to detect automatically if the image belongs to field1 or field2.

So I could alert (".group-container .field1/2 .field-img");

How would I do this?

Thanks for any help

Comment: Use traversal methods to navigate through the DOM: http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(".group-container .field-img").click(function() {
   var field=$(this).parent().attr('id');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to Izzey's solution is to use `.closest` with an attribute starts with selector (or classname because it would be more appropriate for those divs to have a common class)

```
$(".group-container .field-img").click(function() {
    var field = $(this).closest("[id^=field]")[0].id;
});
```

or, with a common classname,

html

```
<div class=group-container>
 <div class="field" id=field1>
  <div class=field-img>
 </div></div>
 <div class="field" id=field2>
  <div class=field-img>
 </div></div>
</div>
```

js

```
$(".group-container .field-img").click(function() {
    var field = $(this).closest(".field")[0].id;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".group-container .field-img").click(function() {
   var field = this.parentNode.id;
   alert (".group-container ." + field + " .field-img");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".group-container .field-img").each(function() {
        $(this).click(function(){   
          var fieldid=$(this).parent().attr('id');
        });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Since one element is inside the other, the click will propagate up anyway, so you could always just bind the click to the parent element and do :

```
$('div[id^="field"]').on('click', function() {
    alert(".group-container "+this.id+" .field-img");
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/rjR2t/)

or even get them all dynamically:

```
$('div[id^="field"]').on('click', function(e) {
    alert('.'+this.parentNode.className+" "+this.id+" ."+e.target.className);
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/rjR2t/1/)

​